# Reactive form dynamically add validators

Tags: angular6, angular-reactive-forms

I have two input box one for entering user's identity no & second for uploading the jpeg of the mentioned identity no.

Both these fields are not **required**. But if the user mentions its identity no then the corresponding file upload should become necessary.

How can I achieve this is reactive forms in angular 6?